# Can someone please explain the code describing the input and output and major steps for the code/ comment the lines

Tags: python

I need help understanding this code, an explanation of what's going on within each line

```
import pickle
LOOK_UP = 1
ADD = 2
CHANGE = 3
DELETE = 4
QUIT = 5

def main():
    emails = {}
    choice = 0
    while choice != QUIT:
        choice = getMenuChoice()
        if choice == LOOK_UP:
            lookUp(emails)
        elif choice == ADD:
            add(emails)
        elif choice == CHANGE:
            change(emails)
        elif choice == DELETE:
            delete(emails)
        else:
            exit

def getMenuChoice():
    print()
    print('Menu')
    print('------------------------------')
    print('1. Look up an email address')
    print('2. Add a new name and email address')
    print('3. Change an existing email address')
    print('4. Delete a name and email address')
    print('5. Quit the program')
    print()
    choice = int(input('Enter the choice: '))
    while choice < LOOK_UP or choice > QUIT:
        choice = int(input('Enter a valid choice: '))
    return choice

def lookUp(emails):
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    print(emails.get(name, 'The specified name was not found.'))

def add(emails):
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    address = input('Enter an email address: ')
    if name not in emails:
        emails[name] = address
        pickle.dump(emails, open("emails.dat", "wb"))
    else:
        print('That name already exists.')

def change(emails):
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    if name in emails:
        address = input('Enter the new address: ')
        emails[name] = address
        pickle.dump(emails, open("emails.dat", "wb"))
    else:
        print('That name is not found.')

def delete(emails):
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    if name in emails:
        del emails[name]
    else:
        print('That name is not found.')

main()
```

Comment: Please make your post prettyer

Comment: StackOverflow really isn't a tutorial site, please see [ask]. We could answer specific questions about the code but the intent of the site is not really to give line by line tutorials.

Comment: No, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions

Comment: The question of "How does this code works" is too broad.  Do you have a question on specific lines or are you missing its design pattern?

Comment: @DarrylG I want to know the main functions used in this code that helped it be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break it down.

1. First and foremost, import all the necessary modules:

`import pickle`

2. Define all the constants *(variables that will never change value in the program)* that you will use:

```
LOOK_UP = 1
ADD = 2
CHANGE = 3
DELETE = 4
QUIT = 5
```

3. For the `main` function, decide how the the program reacts to each of the 5 options the user will choose:

```
def main(): # Main function that calls the other functions
    emails = {} # define an emails dict
    choice = 0 # Predefine choice
    while choice != QUIT:
        choice = getMenuChoice()
        if choice == LOOK_UP:
            lookUp(emails)
        elif choice == ADD:
            add(emails)
        elif choice == CHANGE:
            change(emails)
        elif choice == DELETE:
            delete(emails)
        else:
            exit
```

4. In the `getMenuChoice` function:

```
    print()
    print('Menu')
    print('------------------------------')
    print('1. Look up an email address')
    print('2. Add a new name and email address')
    print('3. Change an existing email address')
    print('4. Delete a name and email address')
    print('5. Quit the program')
    print()
```

displays the menu.

`choice = int(input('Enter the choice: '))`

allows the user input to an integer, and the `int()` wrapper converts the string into an `int`.

Here,

`while choice < LOOK_UP or choice > QUIT:`

the program will keep asking for input until the user inputs a valid option, which in this case, are the numbers between 1 and 5, inclusive.

`return choice`

returns the valid option.

5. In the `lookUp` function,

```
def lookUp(emails):
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    print(emails.get(name, 'The specified name was not found.'))
```

`dict.get()` will return the value for the specified key *(the first argument passed into the brackets)*, if the key exists inside the `dict`. Else, it will return the second argument passed into the brackets, which in this case, is `'The specified name was not found.'`.

---

I've commented the explanations:

```
import pickle

LOOK_UP = 1
ADD = 2
CHANGE = 3
DELETE = 4
QUIT = 5

def main(): # Main function that calls the other functions
    emails = {}
    choice = 0
    while choice != QUIT:
        choice = getMenuChoice()
        if choice == LOOK_UP:
            lookUp(emails)
        elif choice == ADD:
            add(emails)
        elif choice == CHANGE:
            change(emails)
        elif choice == DELETE:
            delete(emails)
        else:
            exit

def getMenuChoice():
    print()
    print('Menu')
    print('------------------------------')
    print('1. Look up an email address')
    print('2. Add a new name and email address')
    print('3. Change an existing email address')
    print('4. Delete a name and email address')
    print('5. Quit the program')
    print()

    choice = int(input('Enter the choice: ')) # User inputs an integer, and the int converts the string into an int
    while choice < LOOK_UP or choice > QUIT: # If the user's input is greater than 5 or smaller than 1, then ask for input again
        choice = int(input('Enter a valid choice: '))
    return choice # Return the valid input

def lookUp(emails):
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    print(emails.get(name, 'The specified name was not found.')) # dict.get() will return the vaur for the specified key, if the key exists inside the dict, else, it will return the second pargument passed into the brackets

def add(emails):
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    address = input('Enter an email address: ')
    if name not in emails: # If the input name does not exist among the keys of the emails dict
        emails[name] = address # Create the name as a key, and the email as the value
        pickle.dump(emails, open("emails.dat", "wb")) # Write the data into emails.dat
    else:
        print('That name already exists.')

def change(emails):
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    if name in emails:
        address = input('Enter the new address: ')
        emails[name] = address
        pickle.dump(emails, open("emails.dat", "wb"))
    else:
        print('That name is not found.')


def delete(emails):
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    if name in emails: # If the input name exists among the keys of the emails dict
        del emails[name] # Remove it from the dict
    else:
        print('That name is not found.')

main()
```